# Undefined value; include var value into table cell

Tags: javascript, html-table

```
 function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
        var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText;
        // var showdata = "test\ntest2"
        var res = showdata.split(",");
        var html = ' <table border="1" width="80%" class ="bordered"> <tr><th></th><th>Taught by</th></tr>';
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length - 1; i++) {
            //  window.alert("value gotten " + res[i]);
            var test = res[i];
        //  document.cookie= "teacher"= test;
     
         //   html += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="vList" value="'+ "122222" + '"><br></td><td>' + test + '</td></tr>';
    html += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="vList" value="'+ test.value + '"><br></td><td>' + test + '</td></tr>';

        }
```

I am trying to put the value of `res[i]` into my radio button so that the user can select, but I seem to always get undefined value. What am I doing wrongly here?

Test has a value and I can print out into another cell but not as a value for the radio button.

Still unresolved, please kindly assist.

Edit: using test will result in the table looking like these.

[image]

Comment: do `console.log(res)` after `var res = showdata.split(",");` and tell us what you get

Comment: i got "undefined" but my <td>' + test + '</td> after the radio button was able to print out the correct values

Comment: it seems that test is a string.. why do you do test.value? it should be just `test` in both places

Comment: what is test.value? If test is not an object simply use test

Answer (score 0):

What is `test`?

if `test` is a string then:

```
html += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="vList" value="'+ test + '"><br></td><td>' + test + '</td></tr>';
```

if `test` is an object with a property called `value` and `label` then:

```
html += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="vList" value="'+ test.value + '"><br></td><td>' + test.label + '</td></tr>';
```

if `test` is a array then with index 0 containing the value and 1 containing the label:

```
html += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="vList" value="'+ test[0] + '"><br></td><td>' + test[1] + '</td></tr>';
```

In Short do this:

```
html += '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="vList" value="'+ test + '"><br></td><td>' + test + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: test is the element of array res[0]. 
i have tried all of the above three. statement using test for 1, and res[i] for the 3rd one. but it all failed :(

Comment: and what is res[0], a string? If yes, then this string gets assigned to test hence test is a string.

Comment: res is a long string of test {item1,2,3,4}, 
so i used var res = showdata.split(","); to split it into a array. 
test is res[0], which is a string?

Comment: if i use the string method, i  will get <!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv= ....

Comment: right res[0] is a string. so you cannot do `test.value` You just need `test`

Comment: the value of the radio button will be "
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63660/discussion-between-user2760642-and-lucky-soni).